# Can't bind to an image while it is in a data-bound itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to display a list of thumbnails for maps. I cannot bind the images source to Thumbnail which is a property of a Map.

```
<ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Maps}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel CanVerticallyScroll="True" Margin="5">
                        <Image Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly" Height="150" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

This is the viewmodel: (Ignore the temporary file paths)

```
  public BindableCollection<MapModel> Maps { get; set; }

        public MapListViewModel()
        {
            Maps = new BindableCollection<MapModel>();

            string projectPath = @"C:\Users\james\Documents\Projects\C#\Stratify";
            string path = projectPath + @"/Maps";

            string[] mapFiles = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

            foreach(string mapFile in mapFiles)
            {
                var mapModel = new MapModel
                {
                    Thumbnail = new BitmapImage(new Uri(mapFile + "/icon.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
                };
                Maps.Add(mapModel);
            }

        }
```

This is the MapModel :

```
public class MapModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private ImageSource thumbnail;
        public ImageSource Thumbnail
        {
            get { return thumbnail; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref thumbnail, value); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have `Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"`, but the property name is `Thumnail`. That won't work. You should have seen data binding errors in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the application.

Comment: Besides that, the property type must not be `Image`. It should be `ImageSource` or perhaps `BitmapSource`. Then you would assign `new MapModel { Thumbnail = bi }`.

Comment: I also doubt that `mapFile + @"/icon.jpg"` is a relative URI.

Comment: @Clemens Just did both but the problem is that the xaml isn't picking up Thumbnail as a property it can bind to. Normaly, the intellisense picks it up but there is nothing.

Comment: Thumnail ( or thumbnail )  should be an BitmapImage rather than image. Image is the control.

Comment: @Clemens it is a relative URI i'm just doing that temporarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property name is wrong. It should be `Thumbnail`, and the property type should be `ImageSource`:

```
public class MapModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ImageSource thumbnail;
    public ImageSource Thumbnail
    {
        get { return thumbnail; }
        set { OnPropertyChanged(ref thumbnail, value); }
    }
}
```

You would assign a BitmapImage like this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(mapFile, "icon.jpg");
var uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var image = new BitmapImage(uri);
var mapModel = new MapModel { Thumbnail = image };
```

Comment: I changed the names already and tried changing what you have said but the same problem is there. XAML isnt picking up Thumbnail as a property.

Comment: "*XAML isnt picking up Thumbnail as a property*" - what does that mean? Are the images not shown when you run the application?

Comment: Usually Thumbnail would pop up when i type '{Binding ' as I have set datacontext in the xaml. Yes the images aren't showing when i run the application

Comment: Don't worry just built it and it worked... I must have not built it after changing. Thanks for the help!